# check Excel files rows in R

Tags: r, excel, csv

My folder has three Excel files. "a.csv, b.csv, c.csv". I want to make sure they have the same number of rows (no need to worry about column).

Question:

1. How to compute the number of rows in each file?
2. Check which file has the smartest rows

I am stuck in R.

My draft R code:

```
  files <- read.csv("C:/Users/files","/",sep="")
  for(i in 1:3)
  {

   filenames<-list()
   files[[i]]<-read.csv(paste("C:/Users/files","/",
                    filenames[i], sep = ""))

   rows<-files[[i]]
   }
   dim(rows)
```

Comment: csv or Excel? Have a look at the responses in [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Fast-way-to-determine-number-of-lines-in-a-file-tt1472962.html#a4693520) on Nabble (BTW - crossposting is discuoraged) - there's probably something that will help. Particularly if the files are (or can be converted to) csv.

Comment: Thank you Dale! I figured it out yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure about the code provided and what do you mean by "same rows". But in case you mean same **rownames**, look at ?rownames and ?identical (alternative: ?all.equal):

```
files <- list()
for (i in c("a", "b", "c")) files[[i]] <- read.csv(file = paste(i, ".csv", sep=""), row.names=1) # assuming rownames where added and files saved e.g. with read.csv
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  print(rownames(files[[i]]))
  if (!identical(rownames(files[[1]]), rownames(files[[i]]))) stop(paste("rownames of file ", i, "differ from file 1!"))
}
```

or use a construction like `all(rownames(files[[1]]), rownames(files[[i]]), ...)`

In case you need just the **number of rows**, use ?nrow (and see ?NROW for curiosity...):

```
sapply(files, nrow) == nrow(files[[1]])
any(sapply(files, nrow) == nrow(files[[1]]))
which(! sapply(files, nrow) == nrow(files[[1]]))
```

=> FALSE for the files that differs from nrow(files[[1]]), or if any file differs, or which (name and nrow given) files differ from the first one)

Comment: Thank you Martin! I want to compute the number of rows in each file. I will try your code first. Thanks for the help!

Comment: added some code that simplifies the task since you said only row numbers matter

Answer (score -1):

`nrow(dataFrame)`
 is your friend